# Importing Python Modules Concurrently Inside Function with Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, module

```
import os
import threading
import queue
import cProfile
```

Is there a way to import modules using a thread?  My code takes 5 seconds to initiate because of the imports. But when I use threading my modules can't be accessed in the threading function.